# How to structure a binary file file header in c?

Tags: c, data-structures

I've created my own file header for a binary file which contains:

- **uint_8 filesignature[4]**
  which should help identifying my file
- **uint_8 CRLF_CR_LF[4]**
  consisting of "\r\n 0x32\n" - helping to identify different line breaks
- **uint_8 version_id**
  version number
- **uint_8 offset_to_data**
  where the first data block starts (useful if header grows in the next version)
- **uint_16 header_size**
  size of the header
- **uint_32 CRC_checksum**
  helpful to test whether the data is correct or faulty
- additional fields which aren't that relevant

This problem lets to basically two questions:

- What is the state-of-the-art order of these informations?
- Is it better to store them in a byte-array or in a struct (WRT packing i.e. #pragma pack)?

**EDIT:**
   The data is stored in little-endian.

Comment: If you want to use a single struct, packing might help but is not sufficient. You also need to care about endianess for any value that is longer than 1 single byte.

Comment: @Gerhardh thanks for your comment I appreciate it. I should probably add, that I store all data in little-endian.

Comment: Can you ensure that your code will never ever be compiled on a big endian machine? Defining byte order within the file is a good idea but you need to ensure that the program is on the same page.

Comment: @Gerhardh well I can't but if I know, that I've saved all data in little-endian and one can check endianess of a system pretty easily, I need two additional functions for fliping endianess or not. That correct or am I missing something?

Comment: That's correct. The posibility that you might need such a conversion during reading your data could affect your design decision. Using a packed struct with its drawbacks wrt alignment etc. becomes less tempting if you need to flip every other field. Then you could just read each field separately and store properly into a non-packed struct. But the final decision is opinion based.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you very much. Is there anything you can tell me from experience etc. about the order of the fields? Is there a preferred order?

Comment: My advice is to avoid struct for accessing binary data. It may work, and later break on a different architecture or compiler. And it is trivial to test endianness: just look at first byte of an integer containing 1. It will be 1 on a little endian system, and 0 on a big endian, whatever the system.